# Secure NestJS SwaggerUI with Keycloak

Tags: nestjs, keycloak, swagger-ui

I am currently trying to build a RestAPI backend using NestJS. I am using SwaggerUI to test and access my endpoints and want to secure those using keycloak.

I am using following line and nest-keycloak-connect to connect my Keycloak client with my project:

```
KeycloakConnectModule.register({authServerUrl: '<URL>', realm: '<RealmName>', clientId: '<clientID>', secret: '<Secret>'});
```

I am setting up SwaggerUI as follows:

```
const config = new DocumentBuilder()
  .setTitle('<Title>')
  .setDescription('Example Description')
  .setVersion('1.0')
  .build();
  const document = SwaggerModule.createDocument(app, config);

  SwaggerModule.setup('api', app, document);
```

Now I would like to know how I can add the "authenticate" button in SwaggerUI so that it sends the given Username and Password as a JWT Token to Keycloak and returns with the access-token so i can access my endpoints according to their given Guards.

My current problem is that the Documentation regarding using NestJS and Keycloak together is rather small as far as I could find. I can either find help regarding Swagger and NestJS without Keycloak, or Swagger and Keycloak using another framework than NestJS.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by Creating a Client (That will be your api) and using the "Resource Owner Password Credentials flow"
https://www.keycloak.org/docs/22.0.4/securing_apps/#_resource_owner_password_credentials_flow

Create your client and then enable Client Authentication at Clients > "yourclient" > Settings

Then under:
Clients > "yourclient" > Credentials
On Client Authenticator select "Client Id and Secret"

Use that information to make a request to your keycloak domains like shown in the docs:

```
    curl \
  -d "client_id=myclient" \
  -d "client_secret=40cc097b-2a57-4c17-b36a-8fdf3fc2d578" \
  -d "username=user" \
  -d "password=password" \
  -d "grant_type=password" \
  "http://localhost:8080/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token"
```